# Persist Object - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am newbie in Entity Framework. I think I have a simple doubt, but I have not found the answer in other posts.

I have:

```
public class A_B
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;

    private A a;
    private B b;
}

public class A
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;
}

public class B
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;
}
```

When I ask entity framework to create object A_B in database, entity framework creates A_B, A and B in database too. I do not want to create objects A and B in the database. A and B are already in the database. I want to save only A_B.

The command to create A_B in the database is:

```
context.Entry(A_B).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

or

```
context.Entry(A_B).State = EntityState.Added;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework are creating the existing objects because are untracked on the context, so the context are creating the entities on database.

You need to track that objects changing state of A and B to Modified to attach to current context and avoid the creation on db.

Comment: How can I do It in my code? Do you have an example?

Comment: You are already changing the state of A_B, its the same way:
context.Entry(A).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(B).State = EntityState.Modified;

Change the state before the SaveChanges method.

Comment: Thank you Daniel,

But is not necessary to modify A and B. Is there other way?

Comment: You don't need to modify object, just change the state to modified for mark that objects as tracked in the context and avoid the duplication on db.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your code based on your database if it is already built/partially built.  Add the nuget packages for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (assuming you're using SQL Server), and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.  Then, you can run a command similar to the below to automatically generate the code.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[servername];Database=[databasename];Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Test
```

Check out [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/entity-framework-core-getting-started/table-of-contents) course for a good introduction to Entity Framework.